# Problem connecting docker containers Unknown MySQL server host

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, mariadb

This is the docker compose file that builds the images and runs the containers

```
version: '3'
services:
  weather_db:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-mariadb
    image: favargasc/weather:latest
    container_name: weather_db
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

  countries_states:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-countries_states
    image: favargasc/countries_states:latest
    container_name: countries_states
    depends_on:
      - weather_db
```

This is the mariadb dockerfile

```
FROM mariadb:latest

COPY init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
RUN chmod 755 /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql

ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=2664
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE=weather
ENV MYSQL_USER=admin
ENV MYSQL_PASSWORD=2664

EXPOSE 3306

CMD ["mysqld"]
```

This is the python dockerfile

```
FROM python:latest

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y default-mysql-client

RUN pip install mysql-connector-python

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

This is the file where I try to connect to the database.

```
import mysql.connector as mysql
import sys


def main():
    # Connect to MariaDB Platform
    try:

        # Establecer la conexión con la base de datos
        cnx = mysql.connect(
            user='admin',
            password='2664',
            host='weather_db',
            port=3306,
            database='weather'
        )

        print("Connecting to mariadb...")

    except mysql.Error as e:
        print(f"Error connecting to MariaDB Platform: {e}")
        sys.exit(1)

    cur = cnx.cursor()
    cnx.close()


main()
```

problem connecting my docker containers "Error connecting to MariaDB Platform: 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host"

I think the problem is the host, but I don't know how I should configure it so that both containers communicate correctly

Comment: While your stack is running, create a shell on `countries_state` (`docker exec containername bash`) and then temporarily install the MySQL console client, and try connecting to `weather_db` using that method. Maybe there are some Docker networking problems between the two containers.

Comment: Check `docker logs` too, to ensure MySQL is still running.

Comment: don't change `CMD` or `EXPOSE` in your MariaDB dockerfile, let it inherit from its base image. Your `countries_states` might be trying to connect too quick.